# Display BusyIndicator during a GoToAsync Call

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, maui, busyindicator

I have a .NET Maui app that loads a list of people from a database. Tapping that person in the ListView then displays an information page about that person.

Although this works well, there is quite a delay while the additional information is pulled from the database after calling GoToAsync:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//people/person", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Person", e.Target } });
```

I have the SyncFusion MAUI suite, and am using the BusyIndicator:

```
<sfCore:SfBusyIndicator VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            IsRunning="{Binding Loading}" AnimationType="Cupertino" Title="Loading..." />
```

If I set my "Loading" property to true, the indicator *does* display correctly.

I've tried wrapping the GoToAsync call:

```
            Loading = true;

            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//people/person", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Person", person } });

            Loading = false;
```

I've also tried *not* wrapping the GoToAsync call in a Task.Run(), have tried calling GoToAsync without awaiting and have tried using the Application Dispatcher to call GoToAsync, but whatever I do, the busy indicator is not shown.

I removed the "Loading = false" call, and when I navigate back to the original search page, my BusyIndicator is doing what it should, so it appears that BusyIndicator is activated *after* GoToAsync has completed.

What's the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: `await Task.Run()` is redundant here

Comment: It seems to me, the page causing the delay should display the waiting indicator, not the one routing to it.

Comment: @nvoigt is correct, if the page that you're navigating to is taking time to load then it should display the indicator.

Comment: Are you loading the data in the page constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like nvoigt said. You can add `BusyIndicator` to the Page (an information page about person).

You can set "Loading = true;" in `OnAppearing` and set "Loading = false" after loading the personal information code